# angularjs click event inside the ngBindHtml directive

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have an angularjs sample code snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/aqs3v1gb/) where i can bind the html tags using `ng-bind-html` directive. But how can I include some other tags like angularjs `ng-click`, `id` tag etc inside ngBindHtml directive like

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="myLink" ng-click="myFunct()">Test</a>`

My sample code is here:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "<a href='#' ng-click='someFunction()'>Test</a>";

    $scope.someFunction = function(){
    alert("Link Clicked");
    };
});
```

FYI, the data is loaded dynamically from server side script and i have to use `ng-bind-html` inside `ng-repeat` directive and i have to pass respective id's to click events something like `ng-click="myFunction(x.id)"` as in [sample 2](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/aqs3v1gb/6/).

Comment: It seems like this could lead to hackers being able to run untrusted javascript/html on your site which would be a bad thing.  You can include static content (or dynamic content from your server I suppose) via an `ng-include`...

Comment: mglison is correct, however if you are in control of the data being displayed and need to do this, for example as templating in a customer cell on a data table (the use case I have used this before).  Then you need to Angular Compile the code.  I'll take a look at the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested @Dr Jones, you need use `$compile` directive.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/jyLdtt6c/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "<button ng-click='someFunction(1)'>{{text}}</button>";
    $scope.text = "Test";
    $scope.someFunction = function(val) {
      console.log(val);
    };
  })
  .directive('bindHtmlCompile', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        bindHtmlCompile: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        scope.$watch("bindHtmlCompile", function(newVal) {
          elem.html('');
          var newElem = angular.element(newVal);
          var compileNewElem = $compile(newElem)(scope.$parent);
          elem.append(compileNewElem);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <h3>
  Write code for test button
  </h3>
    <textarea cols="100" ng-model="myText"></textarea>
    <div bind-html-compile="myText">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```